# Cannot Step after Breakpoint in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-7

I just moved my development environment from a Win XP VM to an Win 7 VM. I reinstalled everything.  When I debug a DLL in Delphi 7, it stops at the breakpoints, but the watched variables say

> process not accessible

and I can not *Step Over* or *Trace Into*. I am using a Host Application, as in the past.

Pretty sure this is some simple mis-configuration error, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Run Delphi 7 as administrator.

Comment: I did run it as administrator (right click, run as administrator) with no improvement.

Comment: I think you need to install Delphi 7 as administrator as well; it needs to be registered as a debug handler and that won't happen when installing as a normal user.

Comment: Are Code Optimizations turned off? When turned on (as for Release) the debugger cannot resolve watches.

Comment: My experience is that I can resolve some Watches, even with Code Optimization turned on, but in this case, neither Watches nor Step work.  It is as if I am not actually looking at the "real" process/program, even though it knew enough to stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: When Delphi is installed, there is a message about replacing some debug handler (Watson?).  Do I need to set this?  How would I go about doing this?  I am running both Delphi 7 and Delphi 2007 on the same machine (as I have done for years) and Delphi 2007 is debugging perfectly.

Comment: I just tried debugging a "regular" program, and that works fine.  So there is something about debugging a DLL, or about the way I have this Project set up, that is causing the problem.

Comment: See this question: [**Process Name Not Visible In Delphi XE Attach to process Dialog - cannot debug**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416231/process-name-not-visible-in-delphi-xe-attach-to-process-dialog-cannot-debug), along with answer and comments.

Comment: Vector8 - Thanks.  I have tried running Delphi 7 as Admin, and this did not help.  Was there some specific comment that you wanted me to try?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when debugging dll but in Delphi 5. I found somewhere on the internet that I should close the IDE and remove *.dsk project file. After that Delphi 5 started to work properly.